# How can I take screenshots of Need For Speed: Undercover?

Tags: need-for-speed-undercover

I have the Steam "edition" of Undercover and it has the quite annoying feature of not playing very nice with screenshotting.

Since Steam actually launches some sort of launcher (*sigh*) that then quits, the overlay doesn't work (and so doesn't F12); also, when I try and press PrtScr, what I get instead is:

[image: a black window]

Is there any non-external non-photo-mode way of taking screenshots of this game?

Comment: Google is kinda useless here :/

Comment: What do you mean with non-fraps? [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com) is very nice to get screenshots and you won't be able to get screenshots without a similar program, so, why not FRAPS?

Comment: Because to me, everything that takes screenshots is similar to FRAPS :) What I meant is, why not FRAPS - if you can explain this we can help with other programs. Like "FRAPS doesn't work", "ok then try [wegame](http://www.wegame.com/)" or "I don't like FRAPS" and then we say "we cannot provide recomendation" and close your question even if you weren't looking for recomendation :) .

Comment: @Roberto I'm rather looking for an answer on the lines of "You can screenshot using PrtScr if you play in windowed mode" or "There is an inbuilt key combination that saves a screenshot in this folder", possibly without the use of 3rd party programs.

Comment: Alright. That Fraps works and PrintScreen doesnt is because of a "neat" little technique called OVERLAY. Overlay things are "put" into the image by the graphics card AFTER the printscreen button can catch it. Nowadays it is used less and less because it kills Aero Glass for example. It was very popular until Windows XP though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a similar screen recording program and take a frame from it.  I generally use fraps, but I am also a big fan of Camtasia Studio which also works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Xfire](http://www.xfire.com/) for this. Its an easy to use client, and will even upload the screenshots for you afterwards.